# Bootstrap, having trouble creating a container that has a colored background and a 250 px height and col-md-12 width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having trouble creating the container with bootstrap that is col-md-12, and has a width of 250px. Here is my code so far, what am I missing? I also have text that needs to be centered along with 5 buttons in place below it.

```css
.container set4 {
 background: black;
 height: 250px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container set4 row col-md-12 text-center">
  <h2>Past Events</h2>

  <div class="button1">
    <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href=
    "http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">ALL EVENTS</a><a class=
    "btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href=
    "http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">CORPORATE</a><a class=
    "btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href=
    "http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">WEDDING</a><a class=
    "btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href=
    "http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">COMMUNITY</a><a class=
    "btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">+</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean a _height_ of 250px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple typo's and where not targeting the correct div, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/9/

`set4` need to be `.set4`
and since you want to target the div `col-md-12` inside the `set4` column you should use the css below.

```
.set4 > .row > .col-md-12{
    background-color: black;
    height: 250px;
}
```